# Find 2 points in X-Y Plane

Tags: c++, geometry, line, computational-geometry, cartesian-coordinates

I have X-Y plane and points (xi, yi) where x, y and i are integers. Now if I draw infinite lines of slope 1 and -1, I have to find those 2 points which either will lie on the same line or if none of them lie then should output:

Case : If atmost 1 point lies on a line the 2nd point should be the point which has minimum distance from the line. In such cases we can draw the line exactly between those 2 points to minimize the distance.

I am not able to find the solution to this problem. My approach was to look at the points in opposite quadrants but I did not get any solution better than O(n^2).

Comment: You question is a bit hard to understand. Can you add a drawing or an example? As a side note, you will get much more positive feedback and help if you show what you have done so far. People don't usually like when the question seems to say "Go on guys, do my homework!". I think that is why your question got downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would transform the points into a different coordinate system that is rotated by 45°:

```
u = x + y
v = x - y
```

If the original points lie on a line with slope 1, their `v` coordinate will be equal. If they lie on a line with slope -1, their `u` coordinate will be equal.

Now, create two lists of points. One sorted by `u`, the other sorted by `v`. Then iterate all the points. To find the point that is closest to the corresponding line, you just have to check the neighbors in the sorted order. If there are neighbors with the same `u`/`v` coordinate, you are done. If not, find the neighbor with the smallest `u`/`v` difference and remember it. Do this for all the points and report the pair with the smallest distance.